# Retrieving values from view state

Tags: asp.net

How can we retrieve value of a sever control from viewstate?

For example if we want to retrieve value of text in texbox server control.

Comment: please describe the question little bit more i have posted the answer according to my understandings about your question

Answer (score 0):

first you have to store the value of text box in the viewstate

viewstate["tboxValue"] = tbox.text;

and now suppose you want to retrieve it in label

lblValue.text = viewstate["tboxValue"].ToString();

Comment: what is the need to store the value in viewstate if it is already stored in the view state.

Comment: in that case you will directly retrieve in the way i have mentioned
and if you need the value in some other page then it will be better to use session.